# How can i search the image on mediaItems search api on when it was uploaded to Google Photos (Not when it was created)

Tags: google-photos, google-photos-api

As we know we can filter the media item base of media item creation date.
But i want to filter the media item base on media uploaded time on Google Photos.
I want to know it is possible with current Google Photos API's?. If Yes then kindly help me.

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently a feature that's supported by the Google Photos Library API. You are correct, the metadata that's returned by the API only includes the creation time at the moment.

You could [file a feature request on the issue tracker](https://developers.google.com/photos/library/support/how-to-get-help#bugs-feature) with a description of your use case for this new feature.